# IllegalArgumentException: columnname is not a field defined in this UDT

Tags: cassandra, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-cassandra

I have the following table structure

```
@Table(value = "employee")
public class Employee implements MapIdentifiable{

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(value = "employee_id", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private String empId;

    @Column(value="info")
    @CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.UDT, userTypeName = "emp_info")
    private EmployeeInfo info;

// getters & setters
}

@UserDefinedType(value = "emp_info")
public class EmployeeInfo {

  @CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.TEXT, userTypeName = "employee_name")
  private String employeeName

// getters & setters
}
```

Whenever I am trying to do a `repository.save(emp)`, I am getting the following error `IllegalArgumentException: employeename is not a field defined in this UDT.`.

I have no reference of any field called 'employeename' in my code or in database, yet I am getting the above mentioned error.

I am have tried, recreating the entire schema and tables but with no luck.

My maven dependencies are as follows

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-extras</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

The same code works if I remove the underscore from my field names. I am not able to figure out my code is not working with underscore in my field names.

Please let me know if I am missing out any information to share.

My stacktrace,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: employeename is not a field defined in this UDT
web_1  |    at com.datastax.driver.core.UDTValue.getAllIndexesOf(UDTValue.java:47)
web_1  |    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractData.set(AbstractData.java:535)
web_1  |    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.writeUDTValueWhereFromObject(MappingCassandraConverter.java:495)
web_1  |    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.write(MappingCassandraConverter.java:353)
web_1  |    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.getWriteValue(MappingCassandraConverter.java:769)
web_1  |    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.getWriteValue(MappingCassandraConverter.java:711)
web_1  |    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.writeMapFromWrapper(MappingCassandraConverter.java:368)
web_1  |    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.write(MappingCassandraConverter.java:343)
web_1  |    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.support.InsertUtil.createInsert(InsertUtil.java:52)
web_1  |    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.support.SimpleCassandraRepository.createInsert(SimpleCassandraRepository.java:110)
web_1  |    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.support.SimpleCassandraRepository.save(SimpleCassandraRepository.java:77)
web_1  |    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
web_1  |    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
web_1  |    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
web_1  |    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
web_1  |    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:377)
web_1  |    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200)
web_1  |    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:641)
web_1  |    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
web_1  |    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
web_1  |    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:590)
web_1  |    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
web_1  |    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
web_1  |    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
web_1  |    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
web_1  |    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
web_1  |    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
web_1  |    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
web_1  |    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
web_1  |    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy136.save(Unknown Source)
web_1  |    at com.hindol.service.EmployeeServiceImpl.createEmployee(EmployeeServiceImpl.java:31)
web_1  |    at com.hindol.EmployeeController.saveEmployee(EmployeeController.java:72)
```

Comment: Can you please attach the stack trace?

Comment: Sure. Added my stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`employeename` comes from your mapped UDT `EmployeeInfo` as it contains the property

```
private String employeeName
```

To alter the name of a UDT field, please us `@Column(…)`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's resolved now. I was indeed using the wrong attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when I was trying to run my Spring app after I added another field to my @UserDefinedType class. My Spring app was not updating my UDT structure, so I had to do that manually.

If your project is brand new, you can simply delete table and UDT from your Cassandra, and then let your Spring app run again to recreate the data model:

```
DROP TABLE employee;

DROP TYPE emp_info;
```

However, if your can't simply drop and recreate your table, you have to use ALTER TYPE command to update your UDT structure. See [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlAlterType.html) for details.